# What does the Ruby method .split("\x0") return?

Tags: ruby, string, methods, terminal, rubygems

In the default skeleton code for a Ruby gem, the `.gemspec` file inside of the `Gem::Specification` class there is this line:

`` spec.files = `git ls-files -z`.split("\x0") `` <- please note the PS at the end of this question

When I run `git ls-files -z` in the terminal I get

`.gitignoreGemfileLICENSE.txtREADME.mdRakefiledogeify.gemspeclib/dogeify.rblib/dogeify/version.rb`

What exactly is the `.split("\x0")` method producing as the output?

PS: In reference to the first line of code, does the `` characters allow the terminal to execute code and combine the result with a Ruby method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The **git(1)** help says:

```
$ git help ls-files
[...]
    -z
        \0 line termination on output.
```

So when you say `git ls-files -z`, it will list the files with zero bytes as delimiters between the file names. You'll see similarly formatted output when you say `find ... -print0` or use `xargs -0`. The reason that you'd use a zero byte as a delimiter is that they can't appear in a file name but any other delimiter (such as a space) can.

Then back in Ruby, you need to unpack that `\x0`-delimited list. If you [`string.split("\x0")`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split), you'll break `string` apart on zero bytes (`"\x0"`) and return the parts as an array; for example:

```
> "where\x0is\x0pancakes\x0house?".split("\x0")
 => ["where", "is", "pancakes", "house?"]
```

So `git ls-files -z` is give you a list of files with zero bytes between the file names and `split("\x0")` breaks that string into an array of file names.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. If there is code in a Ruby file surrounded by backticks: ``, does that mean you can attach a Ruby method on the end of it?

Comment: The backticks are really a method in `Kernel` that returns a String: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-60